Can we convert the following integral equation to a differential equation:$h(r)= \int_0^\infty\frac{f(x)}{e^{r x} + 1} dx$?
Can we convert the following integral equation to a differential equation:$$h(r) =\int_0^\infty\frac{f(x)}{e^{r x} + 1 } dx?$$ Here, $f(x)$ is a non-trivial 'nice' function( whatsoever condition is required like being smooth, sufficiently differentiable, Lebesgue integrable etc).
I came through another examples here on page 21, where it is possible to convert the integral equation into a differential equation using differentiation under integral sign.
The first three derivatives of $h(r)$ using differentiation under integral sign are:
$$  h'(r) =\int_0^\infty -\frac{f(x) \cdot x e^{r x}}{(e^{r x} + 1)^2}dx\\
 h''(r) =\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x) x^2 e^{r x} (e^{2r x} - 1)}{(e^{r x} + 1)^4}dx \\
 h'''(r) =\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x) x^3 e^{r x} (3 e^{3r x} + 2 e^{r x} + 3 e^{r x} - 4 e^{4r x})}{(e^{r x} + 1)^8}dx .$$
I don't see if there is any way to connect them to make a differential equation. I understand it would mostly depend upon the form of $f(x)$ as well, would like to see your thoughts.

Hi, seems that the integral you are suggesting won’t be easily translated into differential equation language. This technique is usually effective when the function under the integral is easy to manipulate and shows a natural pattern under differentiation. However, in this case, the function  $f(x)$  is very generic and can be almost anything.

Your integral equation is similar to the Laplace transform of a function, with the kernel $K=(e^{rx}+1)^{-1}$ instead of $K=e^{-rx}$. If you could find an inverse transform then it could be used to get an ODE.

Are you interested in this precise method or computing this integral whatever the method ultimately ?

Interested in exact method, however would like to  what could be the other methods?

Alternatively, you can consider a little bit more general problem by introducing an auxiliary variable and defining the following function :
$$
g(r,s) := \int_0^\infty \frac{f(sx)}{e^{rx}+1} \,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Taking the derivative with respect to $r$ as you did and then integrating by parts, one gets :
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}g(r,s)
   &= -\int_0^\infty \frac{xe^{rx}f(sx)}{(e^{rx}+1)^2} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
   &= \left[\frac{x}{r}\frac{f(sx)}{e^{rx}+1}\right]_0^\infty - \frac{1}{r} \int_0^\infty \frac{f(sx) + sxf'(sx)}{e^{rx}+1} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
   &= \frac{1}{r}\left(\phi(r,s) - g(r,s) - s\frac{\partial}{\partial s}g(r,s)\right)
\end{align}
$$
where $\phi(r,s) := \left.\frac{xf(sx)}{e^{rx}+1}\right|_{x=0}^{x=\infty}$ represents the (potentially vanishing) boundary term, hence the following PDE in the end :
$$
\left(r\frac{\partial}{\partial r} + s\frac{\partial}{\partial s} + 1\right)g = \phi
$$
It may be solved with the help of the method of characteristics and the original integral will correspond to $g(r,1)$.

Edit : an example with $f(x) = x$ (see comments below).
Having said that, since monomials are the eigenfunctions of the operator $x\partial_x$, it turns out to be easier to work with a series expansion of $g$, namely
$$
g(r,s) = \sum_{n,m\in\Bbb{Z}} a_{nm}r^ns^m.
$$
Considering the particular case $f(x) = x$ with $r > 0$, hence $\phi(r,s) = 0$, this expansion leads to $(n+m+1)a_{nm} = 0 \;\forall n,m \in \Bbb{Z}$, which implies that the only non-vanishing coefficients correspond to $n = -(m+1)$. In consequence, the expansion of $g$ is reduced to
$$
g(r,s) = \sum_{m\in\Bbb{Z}} c_m\frac{s^m}{r^{m+1}}.
$$
Then, one needs to impose some boundary conditions or equivalent constraints. One can deduce straightforwardly from the condition $g(r,0) = 0$ that $m \ge 1$. A fortiori, given that $f$ is the identity map in that very particular case, one knows that $g(r,s) \propto s$, hence $m = 1$ and finally $g(r,s) = c\frac{s}{r^2}$, with $c$ a constant of integration to be determined with the help of an initial condition.

Important remark.
It has to be highlighted that the present method, i.e. computing an integral as the solution of a differential equation, possesses a major flaw : extra solutions.
Indeed, the considered differential equations often have several solutions and even an infinite number of them in the case of linear differential equations, given that the solution sets of the latter form vectorial spaces. Consequently, it is needed to invoke boundary/initial conditions or other constraints over the solutions in order to distinguish them; and even so, it might not be sufficient in the end. Analogously, this method produces extra solutions in the same way we couldn't describe a number as a solution to a quadratic equation without imposing another contraint, because the two roots of a second-order polynomial cannot be distinguished a priori.
Moreover, it might be hard to determine the constants of integrations from initial conditions while avoiding the precise integral we desire to compute at the same time.

Alternative method : the Laplace transform.
Actually, the function $h$ can be interpreted as a Laplace transform. Indeed, if $F$ denotes the Laplace transform of $f$, one gets thanks to the geometric series :
$$
\begin{align}
h(r) &= \int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)}{e^{rx}+1} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
     &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \int_0^\infty f(x)e^{krx} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
     &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k F(k|r|)
\end{align}
$$
when $r < 0$, and
$$
\begin{align}
h(r) &= \int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)}{e^{rx}+1} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
     &= \int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)e^{-rx}}{1+e^{-rx}} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
     &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-(k+1)rx} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
     &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k F((k+1)r)
\end{align}
$$
when $r > 0$, while $h(0) = \int_0^\infty f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$ simply.

interesting. et's take a simple case with $f(x)=x$, then $g(r,s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{f(sx)}{e^{rx}+1} ,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\infty \frac{sx}{e^{rx}+1} ,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{s\pi^2}{12r^2},r>0$. The exact solution is $g(r,1)$. We also see $\phi(r,s)=0$. How do we go from there to PDE?

@stephan  I don't unserstand your question. The PDE is given by the last equation in my answer.

Sorry, I meant, how does the above PDE gives the same solution as $g(r,s)=\frac{s\pi^2}{r^2}$?

Solving PDE gives us arbitrary function in the solution, I don't see how to determine that? The solution is $g(r,s)=\frac{h(\frac{s}{r})}{r}$, where $h$ is arbitrary function. The question is how to determine it using the given integral form of $g$.

@stephan  I've edited my answer to tackle your questions, have a look.

For using Laplace transform, you have interchanged integral and summation, what are the sufficient conditions to do so? Should it be the same conditions that are used for the existence of Laplace transform?

You can go part of the way if you substitute $x$ with $u=rx$.
You then have $x=u/r$ and $dx=\frac{1}{r}du$.
If $r>0$
$h(r)=\frac{1}{r}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(\frac{u}{r})}{e^u+1}du \\
\Rightarrow h'(r)=\frac{-1}{r}h(r)-\frac{1}{r^3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{uf'(\frac{u}{r})}{e^u+1}du
$
and if $r<0$
$h(r)=\frac{-1}{r}\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{f(\frac{u}{r})}{e^u+1}du \\
\Rightarrow h'(r)=\frac{-1}{r}h(r)+\frac{1}{r^3}\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{uf'(\frac{u}{r})}{e^u+1}du
$
and of course $h(0)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ so all $r \in \mathbb{R}$ cases are covered.
Of course you would need to have more info on $f(x)$ to go further but I think that's a given.
Also a bit tangential but if $r>0$ and you have a Taylor series for $f(x)$, then
$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n \\
\Rightarrow h(r) = \frac{1}{r} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!r^n}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^x+1}dx \\
\Rightarrow h(r)  =\frac{f(0)}{r}\ln(2)
+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{r^{n+1}}
(1-2^{-n})\zeta(n+1)$
with $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^x+1}dx = (1-2^{-n})\zeta(n+1)n!$ for $n>-1$.
